# Why do I have an empty space on my page and how do I remove it?

Tags: html, css

I followed instructions to make a navigation bar that uses radio buttons to show and hide elements.

It's working great! However, now I have an empty space before most of these elements, and after some of them. I would like there to be no such empty spaces (basically blank areas that must be scrolled down to).

This is my code:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f9f7f0;
  color: #333333;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

header {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.logo {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 48px;
  margin: 5px 0 0 -156px;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 330px;
  filter: invert(4%) sepia(44%) saturate(3197%) hue-rotate(239deg) brightness(89%) contrast(92%);
}

.subtitle {
  font-size: 32px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #d4a255;
}

main {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.section {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  color: #333333;
}

.section:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 199, 95, 0.7), rgba(255, 199, 95, 255));
}

.content {
  padding: 40px 40px 25px 40px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  min-height: 350px;
  /*! display: flex; */
}

h2 {
  font-size: 36px;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  /*! text-align: center; */
  /*! min-width: 532px; */
}

p {
  font-size: 18px;
  /*! margin: -9px; */
  margin-block-start: 101px;
  /*! margin-block-end: -21px; */
  /*! align-content: end; */
  /*! align-self: end; */
  /*! display: flex; */
  align-self: flex-end;
}

footer {
  background-color: #f9f7f0;
  padding: 20px 0;
  color: #333333;
  text-align: center;
}

footer p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}


/* Background images for each section */

.missao {
  background-image: url('missao.webp');
  /* Placeholder address for Missão section */
}

.ameacas {
  background-image: url('ameacas.webp');
  background-position-y: -200px;
}

.pontosfortes {
  background-image: url('pontosfortes.jpeg');
  background-position-y: -121px;
  background-position-x: 81px;
}

.pontosfracos {
  background-image: url('pontosfracos.webp');
  background-position-y: -126px
}

.descricao {
  background-image: url('descricao.webp');
  background-position-y: -174px;
}

.foco {
  background-image: url('foco.webp');
  background-position-y: -37px;
}

.diferenciais {
  background-image: url('diferenciais.webp');
  background-position-y: -37px;
}

.estrategias {
  background-image: url('estrategias.jpeg');
  background-position-y: -348px;
}


/* Add more section classes with background images as needed */

.logo-wrapper {
  animation: fadeIn 0.5s forwards;
}

.logo-wrapper.fade-out {
  animation: fadeOut 0.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}


/* Detect scroll event and apply fade-out animation */

body.scrolled-down .logo-wrapper {
  animation: fadeOut 0.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.white-square {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -79px;
  left: 23px;
  width: 76%;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.fade-out .white-square {
  opacity: 0;
}

.pastel-square {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  width: 24%;
  height: 135px;
  background-color: #fdc8b0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  bottom: -33px;
}

.fade-out .white-square {
  opacity: 0;
}

.logobox {
  position: relative;
}


/* Hide the toggle checkbox */

#plano-negocios {
  display: none;
}

#localizacao {
  display: none;
}

#contato {
  display: none;
}


/* Hide expandable content by default */

.planonegocios-conteudo {
  visibility: collapse;
}

.localizacao-conteudo {
  visibility: collapse;
}

.contato-conteudo {
  visibility: collapse;
}


/* Show hidden content when the checkbox is checked */

#plano-negocios:checked~*.planonegocios-conteudo {
  visibility: visible;
}

#localizacao:checked~*.localizacao-conteudo {
  visibility: visible;
}

#contato:checked~*.contato-conteudo {
  visibility: visible;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  /* Banner */
  --banner-outer-height: 100vh;
  --banner-inner-height: 5vh;
  --banner-height-difference: calc( var(--banner-outer-height) - var(--banner-inner-height));
  --banner-bg: #ffc75f;
  /* Header */
  --header-outer-height: 110px;
  --header-inner-height: 70px;
  --header-bg: #FFF;
}

body {
  font-family: "DM Sans", sans-serif;
  background-color: #f2f5f7;
  line-height: 1.5;
  min-height: 300vh;
  position: relative;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
}

.responsive-wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}


/* Sticky banner */

.banner-outer {
  /* Make it stick */
  height: var(--banner-outer-height);
  position: sticky;
  top: calc(var(--banner-height-difference) * -1);
  /* Multiply by -1 to get a negative value */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* Other */
  background-color: var(--banner-bg);
  z-index: 2;
  background-image: url(headerbackground.jpg);
  background-size: 144%;
  background-position-x: -151px;
}

.banner-outer:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 199, 95, 0.5), rgba(255, 199, 95, 255));
}

.banner-inner {
  /* Make it stick */
  height: var(--banner-inner-height);
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  /* Other */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.25;
  z-index: 2;
}

.header-outer {
  height: 15vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: var(--header-bg);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  top: 5vh;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 2
}

.header-inner {
  height: var(--header-inner-height);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


/* Styling of other elements */

.header-logo img {
  display: block;
  height: calc(var(--header-inner-height) + 20px);
}

.header-navigation {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.header-navigation a,
.header-navigation button {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  color: #000000;
  margin-left: 1.75rem;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.header-navigation a {
  display: none;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header-navigation button {
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0;
}

.header-navigation a:hover:after,
.header-navigation button:hover:after {
  transform: scalex(1);
}

.header-navigation a:after,
.header-navigation button:after {
  transition: 0.25s ease;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: currentcolor;
  transform: scalex(0);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: 0;
}

.main {
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .header-navigation a {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .header-navgitaion button {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&amp;family=Roboto:wght@400;700&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


<body class="scrolled-down">
  <div class="banner-outer">
    <div class="banner-inner responsive-wrapper">
      <!-- Placeholder logo in SVG format -->
      <div class="logo-wrapper">
        <div class="white-square"></div>
        <div class="pastel-square"></div>
        <img src="logo.svg" class="logo fade-out" alt="Company Logo" />
      </div>
      <!-- End of placeholder logo -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <header class="header-outer">
    <div class="header-inner responsive-wrapper">
      <div class="header-logo">
        <img src="logo2.svg" />
      </div>
      <nav class="header-navigation">
        <a href="#"><label for="plano-negocios" id="a">Plano de Negócios</label></a
        >
        <a href="#"><label for="localizacao" id="a">Localização</label></a>
        <a href="#"><label for="contato" id="a">Contato</label></a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <main>
    <nav class="header-navigation"></nav>

    <input id="plano-negocios" name="navbar" type="radio" /><input id="localizacao" name="navbar" type="radio" /><input id="contato" name="navbar" type="radio" />
    <div class="localizacao-conteudo">
      <!-- Content for "About Us" section with Google Maps map -->
      <!-- Replace this with your Google Maps embed code -->
      <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d248789.81007519642!2d-0.24168169117477634!3d51.52877184119049!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x487604e9773e46e5%3A0x52963a5addd52a99!2sLondon%2C%20UK!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1647455567883!5m2!1sen!2suk"
        width="600" height="450" style="border: 0" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="contato-conteudo">
      <!-- Content for "Contact Us" section with contact information and "Join Us" ad block -->
      <div class="content">
        <h2>Contato</h2>
        <div class="contact-info">
          <p><strong>Endereço:</strong> Rua Exemplo, 1234 - Cidade, Estado</p>
          <p><strong>Telefone:</strong> (123) 456-7890</p>
          <p><strong>Email:</strong> info@exemplo.com</p>
        </div>
        <div class="join-us">
          <h3>Junte-se a nós!</h3>
          <p>
            Estamos sempre em busca de talentos. Envie seu currículo para careers@exemplo.com.
          </p>
          <!-- Replace this with your "Join Us" ad block content -->
          <img src="join-us-image.jpg" alt="Join Us Image" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="planonegocios-conteudo">
      <section id="missao" class="section missao">
        <div class="content">
          <h2>Missão e Objetivos Estratégicos</h2>
          <p>
            A missão da TIME Design de Serviço é revitalizar a estrutura e a qualidade dos serviços prestados por empresas na região, melhorando as relações e a satisfação dos clientes e do ambiente de trabalho. Nossos objetivos estratégicos incluem a otimização
            do fluxo de informação, aprimoramento da experiência do usuário e a criação de um ambiente de trabalho mais positivo e produtivo.
          </p>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section id="ameacas_oportunidades" class="section ameacas">
        <div class="content">
          <h2>Ameaças e Oportunidades</h2>
          <p>
            As ameaças incluem a resistência das empresas conservadoras à mudança e a concorrência de outras empresas de consultoria. No entanto, as oportunidades são vastas, pois muitas empresas estão buscando melhorias em seus processos e estão abertas a novas
            abordagens que possam otimizar seus negócios, aumentar sua competitividade e oferecer soluções inovadoras e personalizadas para as necessidades específicas de cada cliente.
          </p>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section id="pontos_fortes" class="section pontosfortes">
        <div class="content">
          <h2>Pontos Fortes</h2>
          <p>
            A TIME Design de Serviço destaca-se pela sua abordagem centrada no cliente e na melhoria da experiência do usuário, além da expertise de sua equipe em identificar e implementar soluções eficazes para otimizar os processos de trabalho das empresas com
            análise detalhada dos processos, prototipagem rápida e estratégias de melhoria do ambiente de trabalho.
          </p>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section id="pontos_fracos" class="section pontosfracos">
        <div class="content">
          <h2>Pontos Fracos</h2>
          <p>
            Os pontos fracos incluem a necessidade de enfrentar a resistência à mudança por parte de algumas empresas e a dependência da economia regional, a possibilidade da dependência de um modelo de negócios baseado em consultoria poder limitar a capacidade de
            escalar rapidamente, e a possibilidade da empresa enfrentar desafios para atrair clientes em um mercado competitivo.
          </p>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section id="descricao_produto" class="section descricao">
        <div class="content">
          <h2>Descrição do Produto/Serviço</h2>
          <p>
            O serviço que a empresa oferece é uma melhoria na estrutura de trabalho das empresas, otimizando o fluxo de informações e melhorando a experiência do usuário, não só dos clientes da empresa, por meio de melhorias na qualidade do serviço prestado, mas
            também melhorando a experiência do usuário que trabalha na empresa, tornando-a um lugar melhor para se trabalhar. Um período de imersão é feito pelos pesquisadores da TIME na empresa que está sendo estudada, onde cada processo de trabalho
            e tarefa é entendido e analisado para ver áreas de melhoria, sistemas, fluxogramas, planilhas que podem ser desenvolvidos para eles pela TIME, ciclos de informação que podem ser automatizados e assim economizar minutos, até horas e dias de
            trabalho. Durante essa imersão, a TIME também oferece Happy Hours para obter noções acerca das dinâmicas sociais dos funcionários, bem como para inicializar processos de melhorias na atmosfera emocional do local de trabalho.
          </p>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section id="foco_negocio" class="section foco">
        <div class="content">
          <h2>Foco do Negócio</h2>
          <p>
            O foco da TIME Design de Serviço está em ajudar empresas de serviços a otimizar suas operações, melhorar a satisfação do cliente e criar um ambiente de trabalho mais positivo e produtivo para seus funcionários. Empresas de comércio podem ter suas operações
            otimizadas, mas empresas de prestação de serviços podem se beneficiar mais diretamente da carga horária de trabalho reduzida.
          </p>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section id="diferenciais_produtos" class="section diferenciais">
        <div class="content">
          <h2>Diferenciais dos Produtos/Serviços</h2>
          <p>
            Nosso diferencial está na combinação de consultoria especializada em serviço com intervenções práticas e expertise técnica em design de serviço, com imersão detalhada nas empresas-cliente, prototipagem rápida e eventos de integração, e a oferta de soluções
            personalizadas e inovadoras para atender às necessidades específicas de cada cliente.
          </p>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section id="estrategias_venda" class="section estrategias">
        <div class="content">
          <h2>Estratégias de Venda/Marketing</h2>
          <p>
            As estratégias de venda e marketing da TIME Design de Serviço serão conduzidas principalmente por meio das redes sociais e visitas direcionadas às empresas-alvo. Ofereceremos uma consulta gratuita, pesquisa e happy hour, onde a TIME desenvolverá um protótipo
            de solução para os desafios imediatos enfrentados pela empresa em seu pipeline de execução. Isso nos permite demonstrar o valor de nossos serviços e conquistar a confiança das empresas interessadas em melhorar suas operações.
          </p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </main>

  <footer>
    <div class="container">
      <p>© 2024 TIME Design de Serviço. Todos os direitos reservados.</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: The best I can do with all the code in your question is [this](https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/yLrMypp). Can you explain which empty spaces you're talking about?

Comment: First of all, those labels should really not be put into links. The links don't _add_ anything here, they just make the whole semantics worse. And those blank spaces probably stem from the fact that you used `visibility: collapse` to hide your sections - which works the same as `visibility: hidden`, and leaves the space the element would take, if it _was_ visible, reserved. Switch to using the `display` property instead.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware examples of blank spaces: https://i.imgur.com/dNbBBaX.png https://i.imgur.com/MdVJy5j.png https://i.imgur.com/UHXTYoj.png

Comment: @CBroe I made them as links because of my limited coding knowledge, as I wanted to preserve the styling of a navbar that I found available on a codepen, with hover and after, but I wasn't able to make those properties work on the radio labels. EDIT: thank you! Changing to display:none and display:block worked!! Thank you so much

Comment: Put your code thro' a validator before going further. You have duplicate ids and also a label within an anchor element is not valid. There is also a spelling mistake, check spellings of navigation.

Comment: _"but I wasn't able to make those properties work on the radio labels"_ - then that warrants some more looking into. Basically you're just styling text content here, so whether that is inside an `a` or a `label` element, should really not make much of a difference.

Comment: I will look into that, thank you all for the advice!